# Algorithms for adding hydrogens on a molecule

Tags: algorithms, simulation, molecular-dynamics

I want to add hydrogens to some linear polymer molecules (polyethylenes).

I know some working methods like using PyMOL internal function h_add. This method works, but hydrogens are added at distances from the backbone carbon atoms that vary from 1.07 to 1.1 Ångstroms. I need to control the hydrogen distances from the backbone atoms and also the HCH and CCH angles to constant values that I choose every time (for example, H–C = 1.5 Å, ∠HCH = 108.5°, ∠CCH = 109.5°).

Is there a geometry algorithm which I can use to understand the process of hydrogen adding? I know that it can be implemented nicely to a Fortran code but is there an easier way to do this, e.g. a script in Python, or better yet, a bash script?

The molecule coordinate files I am using are in the PDB format.

Comment: For a quick working hack, could you not add them at the "random" distances you describe, then run a step or two of MD (possibly with constraints) to relax everything to their correct positions? I suppose this would not really work if you are adding hydrogens to a ready trajectory, though. I think the algorithm should not be too difficult to write if you really are only interested in carbon chains. Stuff get more complicated with more complex molecules, though, with each atom type requiring their own placements. Have you tried other ready-made codes, such as GROMACS's `g_protonate`?

Comment: I have used g_protonate function but I cannot change the distance of adding hydrogens. I think that gromacs uses these distances as parameters and so I have to change the value of this parameter to 0.11 by hand. That means interfering with the code and this should not be easy!